# Excel smaller greater function not working as expected

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I recently experienced a curious problem related to a formula with the <> operators. Assume that I have the following cells:

In `A2` I have the formula `=TODAY()`

In `B2` I have an alphanumerical string, say `QWRSTY-11`. The last two numbers represent the calendar week

In `C2` I have the following formula
`=IF(ISOWEEKNUM(A2)<RIGHT(B2,2),"X","0")`

Since today is June 15, 2016 and the week number is 24, the formula should return `"0"`. Instead, it returns `"X"`.

To double check my formulas, in `D2` I entered the following:
`=ISOWEEKNUM(A2)-RIGHT(B2,2)`
This formula returns `"13"`, which is correct!!

I don’t understand what’s happening here. I used Evaluate formula but it did not provide any clues. Google wasn’t helpful either. 
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

EDIT

My bad, I did not fully test the solution Jordan proposed. Adding the N function doesn’t work. For instance, if the string in B2 is changed with something like QWRSTY-88, the formula in C2 returns “0”. I used Evaluate formula to understand what is going on. It appears that “88” is treated as text, thus N(“88”) returns “0”. 
Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: You're missing some of the formula for cell C2 as you currently haven't stated the `TRUE` or `FALSE` conditions or included a right parenthesis for the `IF` function.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, something went wrong in editing my post. Now it is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: use the function VALUE to convert the text extracted with the Right function.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you are comparing a text value to a numeric value. Try converting the text extracted with the `Right` function by using `N`:

```
=IF(ISOWEEKNUM(A2)<N(RIGHT(B2,2)),"X","0")
```

Comment: It works! I am still surprised that the N function is not needed when subtracting. Anyway, thanks a lot. Have a great day